# Exclude single .java file from Dependency?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have a dependency to an other project like this:

```
dependencies {

  compile (project(':myProject'))

}
```

I want to exclude `SomeClass.java` from `myProject`.

**How can I exclude a single .java file from a compile dependency?**

Answer (score 0):

You should split module `:myProject` in two modules: `:myProject` and `:myProjectWithSomeClass`. The latter should depend on the former.

In the modules that do not need `SomeClass` you can keep on depending on `:myProject`. All other modules must use `:myProjectWithSomeClass`.